# Significance of having remainder $3$ when divided by $4$ for both $p$ and $q$ in BBS

Tags: prime-numbers, number-theory, blum-blum-shub

In the [Blum Blum Shub random number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum_Blum_Shub), we take two random prime numbers $p$ and $q$ such that both have a remainder of $3$ when divided by $4$. My question is why can't we just take any $2$ random primes? What is significance of having remainder $3$ when divided by $4$ from the perspective of mathematics and security?

Answer (score 2):

This is in order to maximise the state space of the generator after multiple steps. After $s$ steps, the BBS generator will have state $i^{2^s}\mod N$ where $i$ is the initial seed and $N$ is the modulus.

In particular then, the state must be $2^s$th power modulo $N$. The number of residues modulo $N$ that are $2^s$th powers is the product of the number of $2^s$th powers modulo $p$ times by the number of $2^s$th powers modulo $q$ and so we would like to maximise both of these.

The number of distinct $2^s$th powers modulo a prime $p$ is $(p-1)/2^{\mathrm{min}(s,k)}$ where $2^k$ is the largest power of $2$ that divides $p-1$. To minimise this we choose primes $p$ where $k=1$ (resp. $q$). These are the primes that are 3 modulo 4 and for these the number of $2^s$th powers will be $(p-1)/2$ (resp. $(q-1)/2$) and so the number of $2^s$th powers modulo $N$ will be $(p-1)(q-1)/4$.

Comment: Isn't it crucial to the reduction from QR/Factoring to pseudorandomness/inversion too (Lemma 1, Claims 2 and 3 in the [SICOMP version](https://www.math.tamu.edu/~rojas/bbs.pdf) of the paper)? Also, not sure whether the primes being $3 \bmod 4$ is sufficient to ensure a large state-space (conditions stated in Theorem 8 do suffice). Am I missing something here?

Comment: @ckamath Claims 2 and 3 in the paper hold for moduli where the primes are not 3 mod 4, but are easiest to prove in this case. The primes being 3 mod 4 is sufficient to establish a large state-space, but the additional conditions are required to demonstrate a large cycle length.

Comment: Could you point me to some references? This is not obvious to me.

Comment: I don't have a reference to hand, but it is all elementary number theory. If you want to set up a chat room, I can go through some of it.

Comment: I see. Will try to work it out.